# Modify font size in webview or remove some html language on text

Tags: c#, html, uwp, font-size

I have a webview to read data on a database containing html language elements, eg:

, etc and there is also to display images from the database. I want the font size to be bigger.
XAML:

```
<WebView x:Name="QuestionTextWeb" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,10,0,10" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Code:

```
string QuestionPhrase = @"SELECT * FROM DBQUESTION WHERE QUIZT_ID='100'";
question = objConn.Prepare(QuestionPhrase);
QuestionTextWeb.NavigateString((question[1].ToString());
```

How to make the font size bigger? Or is there a way to not show html language (but also to display images) from the database, in addition to using webview? Due to the many html languages contained in it, so can not use replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) method to inject javascript code and use this JS code to change the font side on the html page.

For example:

```xml
<WebView x:Name="webview" DOMContentLoaded="webview_DOMContentLoaded"></WebView>
```

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    string html = "<p>Dessy pergi ke pasar dia ingin membeli beberapa macam diantaranya buah apel, cendol, kain untuk pelajaran keterampilan membatik dan pensil. Ukuran-ukuran yang benar dipakai oleh penjual adalah...</p> ";
    webview.NavigateToString(html);
}

private async void webview_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByTagName(\"p\")[0].style.fontSize=\"" + 30 + "\";" });
}
```

In general, I call this method when [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded). Please make your own decision according to your situation.

Comment: @Rose You could not copy my code into your project directly. It's just my code sample. You would need to modify it by your html page. See [HTML DOM Style fontSize Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontsize.asp)

Comment: For the data displayed is not a html page, but the text in the database containing html elements, such as <p>, <img>, etc. Example: <p> Where is the sun rising? </p>. And there is also a text that does not contain the element.

Comment: @Rose  Please give me a sample value of the `question[1].ToString()`.

Comment: this is the sample: <p>Dessy pergi ke pasar dia ingin membeli beberapa macam diantaranya buah apel, cendol, kain untuk pelajaran keterampilan membatik dan pensil. Ukuran-ukuran yang benar dipakai oleh penjual adalah...</p>

Comment: @Rose I've made a code sample for you. Please see my above edited reply. By the way, I suggested that you could learn some javascript relevant technology :)

Comment: If using, <p> and <img>, does the same use the code above? For example: <p><img src="../../../upload/6.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p>Bakteri adalah mahluk yang sangat kecil walaupun gambar di bawah ini dapat kamu perhatikan cukup besar, cara melihat bateri ini menggunakan mikroskop. Dengan mikroskop perlu tambahan alat lagi agar dapat dilihat lebih besar seperti gambar ini. Karena sangat kecilnya ukuran yang digunakan tidak seperti kita gunakan sehari-hari, ukuran yang digunakan untuk mengukur bakteri adalah ....</p>
Because some contain only <p>, <img>, both, or none at all.

Comment: I got error message like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U-UiW2gj6KjMtcNER when the question does not contain the <p> element, for example: Terhadap orang yang lebih tua, kita harus ....

Comment: @Rose If the question doesn't contain the "<p>" element, you could add a pair of `<p></p>`  to wrap it like this: `string html ="<p>" +"Terhadap orang yang lebih tua, kita harus"+"</p>";webview.NavigateToString(html);` Understand?

Comment: And what if there is a <p> <img> tag? Because there is also <p> <img> in the text displayed on the webview and in the form of data bindings. So there are only <p>, <p> <img>, <img>, and there are no tags. And I want if there is <img>, the image can also be displayed

Comment: @Rose Have you tried to add a pair of `<p></p>` to wrap the `(question[1].ToString()` to see if it will work? I meant that you do not need to care about if there're other html tags, you just add an extra `<p><p>` to wrap it and make the javascript code work.

Comment: yes, it work. Thank you
I have another question related to this topic at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018047/uwpcdisplay-binding-text-in-webview-in-listbox