# [UWP][C#]Display binding text in webview in listbox

Tags: c#, sqlite, webview, uwp

I have a webview in the listbox to display some options in the form of data bindings from the database (the number of options displayed according to the number of options in the database). I use webview because the answer option exists that contains the

tag.

Database:

[image: database]

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ListOption" Grid.Row="4" xmlns:m="using:KipinATM_Win10.Tryout.Models" SelectionChanged="ListAlternatives_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="m1:DBOPTION">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <WebView Margin="4" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Code:

```
int i = 0;
            while (alternative.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                Items.Add(new DBOPTION(Convert.ToInt32(alternative[0]), alternative[1].ToString(), int.Parse(alternative[2].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(alternative[3])));
                if (int.Parse(alternative[2].ToString()) == 1)
                {
                    thisquestioncorrectindex = i;
                }
                i++;
            }

            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = Items;
            ListOption.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

DBOPTION.cs:

```
[SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey]
        public int _id { get; set; }

        public string LABEL { get; set; }

        public int IS_CORRECT { get; set; }

        public int QUESTION_ID { get; set; }

        public DBOPTION()
        {
        }

        public DBOPTION(int ID, string Label, int IsCorrect, int QuestionID)
        {
            _id = ID;
            LABEL = Label;
            IS_CORRECT = IsCorrect;
            QUESTION_ID = QuestionID;
        }
```

I have trouble displaying the answer option on webview. How to display it in webview in listbox?

Note: 
Text displayed on the webview is a text in the LABEL column of the database

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think you need to use [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView) control inside `DateTemplate` of `ListBox`, `TextBlock` or some other controls could just simply meet your requirements. For "because the answer option exists that contains the tag" you mentioned, if you mean the scenario for the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Tag) property, which is to provide an general-purpose property on all `FrameworkElement` classes that supports data binding.

If you do want to binding text to `WebView`, you need to use [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-attached-properties) since `WebView`  doesn't have a property to bind to. Details for how to do please reference [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties/).

For example:

```
<ListBox Name="ListOption" Grid.Row="4" xmlns:m="using:KipinATM_Win10.Tryout.Models"   >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DBOPTION">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <WebView Margin="4" local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding LABEL}" Height="300" Width="300" Tag="{Binding _id}"/>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LABEL}" Tag="{Binding _id}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<DBOPTION> Items;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DBOPTION>()
        {
            new DBOPTION()
            {
               _id=1,LABEL="test1",IS_CORRECT=1,QUESTION_ID=3
            },
             new DBOPTION()
            {
                _id=1,LABEL="test1",IS_CORRECT=1,QUESTION_ID=3
            },
              new DBOPTION()
            {
                 _id=1,LABEL="test1",IS_CORRECT=1,QUESTION_ID=3
            }
        };

        Binding myBinding = new Binding();
        myBinding.Source = Items;
        ListOption.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
    }

    private void ListAlternatives_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class DBOPTION
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string LABEL { get; set; }
    public int IS_CORRECT { get; set; }

    public int QUESTION_ID { get; set; }

 }
class MyProperties
{
    // "HtmlString" attached property for a WebView
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlStringProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HtmlString", typeof(string), typeof(MyProperties), new PropertyMetadata("", OnHtmlStringChanged));

    // Getter and Setter
    public static string GetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlStringProperty); }
    public static void SetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(HtmlStringProperty, value); }

    // Handler for property changes in the DataContext : set the WebView
    private static void OnHtmlStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView wv = d as WebView;
        if (wv != null)
        {
            wv.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the webview in the listbox that contains the LABEL is empty, like the image I circled: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U-Uokm5GjrOMmRNwi

Comment: @Rose That's will be something wrong with your binding. I upload the completed minimal demo for testing that can work well you could test and check your code snippet.

Comment: I tried your code, but i have a trouble: the text on the webview is displayed only one. How to handle it?

Comment: " the text on the webview is displayed only one." What does this mean?

Comment: The data shown only 1. That is the data on the index to 0 only

Comment: @Rose, on my side, all the  `Items` could display. I'm not sure what's wrong with your side, could you please provide a [mcve] and a screenshot?